# How can I get the 'Can't Touch This!' archievement?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I’m on the way to get some achievements done, then I came across the "Can't Touch This!" achievements.

[image]

I tried several ways to get it, but so far no idea did work. Has someone already got this achievement and knows how to solve this?

Comment: thx for edidting :D i would have puta picture in but well not enough points/rights as far :D

Comment: Don't worry, keep asking questions whenever your stuck and you'll gain the rep eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raven's seeker missile is not an instant attack... it slowly travels towards its target and when it reaches it, it blows up. To get the achievement, you have to run away from the missile until it runs out of gas so to speak. They last 15 seconds, so if you can keep away that long, you will earn this achievement. You will need a fast-moving unit to do this.

Comment: well we tried this yesterday but it didnt work, we used a banshee to flay away. maybe we need to test it more :D

Comment: well didnt got the time to test but its the only way to make it, coze waht i remember is the 20%(or 10%) dodge upgrade from the campaign :-D

Answer (score 5):

The reapers are a great unit to use for dodging the seeker missile as they are quite quick, even faster with the speed boost.

This is a "Melee" achievement, so make sure your game is not custom, but Melee instead. Also you cannot dodge a **friendly** seeker missile to get this achievement. It has to be an **opponent's** seeker missile.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this one is to play as Zerg and have a speedling on creep. You really don't have to try to outrun if you play it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use Phoenixes as Protoss. They don't even come close.

Answer (score 0):

Get a friend.  Create a custom melee game, 1v1.  Have one be terran and the other toss.  One makes ravens, the other phoenix.  Easy.  You can also get a few other in this game, like kill 20 units with a high templar, and repair 8 burning buildings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stay away from it, hide in the fog of war as soon as the raven summoned it. It will malfunction and you get your achievement. Works on me and my friend (HotS expansion.)